# Bidirectional binding in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reflection

I have ASP.NET pages with a lot of controls, and I'm looking for a way to populate model objects automatically from the page's controls. Is there any framework that do that, or should I implement it by hand by using something like reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Implement IBindableComponent on your model objects. Samples at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/73de165c-e948-4015-bdcd-570f55a6e365